# How do you add a custom title bar to an Electron app?

Tags: javascript, electron

I want to create a custom title bar / controls to show above the remote URL that is loaded in an electron app.

For example, let's say i have a file called `title.html`:

```html
<div>
    <button onclick="window.history.forward()">Go Forward</button>
    <button onclick="window.history.back()">Go Back</button>
</div>
```

let's say i'm loading the youtube URL in my electron app:

```js
const createWindow = () => {
    const window = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        titleBarStyle: 'hiddenInset',
    })

    window.loadURL('https://youtube.com')
}
```

how do i have my `title.html` always show above youtube so i can add back & forward  buttons and other stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the strategy here is to load your `title.html` into the `BrowserWindow`, and then create a `BrowserView` that hosts youtube and position it appropriately.

(In my app, I use `frame: false` and not `hiddenInset`, but hopefully a similar idea can apply here)

```
import * as path from "path";
import { BrowserWindow, BrowserView } from "electron";

const TITLEBAR_HEIGHT = 50; // px

const createWindow = () => {
    const window = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600, titleBarStyle: 'hiddenInset' })
    const browserView = new BrowserView({ webPreferences: { sandbox: true, contextIsolation: true });
    window.setBrowserView(browserView);
    
    // load your titlebar page
    await window.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, "./index.html"))

    // position the titlebar
    const contentBounds = window.getContentBounds();
    browserView.setBounds({ x: 0, y: 0, width: contentBounds.width, height: contentBounds.height - TITLEBAR_HEIGHT });
    browserView.setAutoResize({ width: true, height: true });

    browserView.loadURL('https://youtube.com');    
}
```

And you'd set up the height of your titlebar in your stylesheet:

```
<div id="titlebar>
    ...
</div>
```

```
#titlebar {
    height: 50px;
}
```